# how to get list of recent changes made to keymap in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have made recent changes in intellij keymap altering keys to my preference , but it turns out a few changes overwrote a few important features .

I want to revert only recent changes like a day old or two . how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. IntelliJ IDEA does not keep a history of keymap changes; it stores only the latest state.